# Laptop overheats at 50c

Tags: hardware-failure, heatsink

Laptop hinge started clicking out of place. Clicked it back into place then it crashed. Since then it will freeze whenever it reaches 50c then I will have to forcefully shut it down. It will not come back on immediately, instead giving me some error code via blinking lights, but will come on after it has cooled off for a while

I've had it cleaned and paste reapplied, the hinge fixed, diagnostics run and all coming back positive, yet the problem persists. Official support, which is quite limited for a variety of reasons, tells me this though - the problem is most likely the heatsink.

True enough, if I examine the exhaust closest to the hinge that was clicking, it looks slightly damaged - some of the 'pins' there are bent, which was possibly caused by heat. But still I wonder...

So my question is - could a damaged heatsink explain my laptops behaviour, ie crashing at 50c as if it were overheating? Thanks

Comment: I would go back and re-check you have applied the thermal paste properly. apoor application will prevent the heatsink working. The gauge may only ready 50c but the core may be getting much hotter. It's also possible the damage is shorting the metal of the case somewhere. Open it all up again and check for exposed wire.

Comment: It is extremely difficult to mess up applying thermal paste. I watched a video where a guy compared all kinds of methods including putting way too much and way too little on and stress testing. The difference was less than 1 degree for all methods except not enough paste, which was something like 2-3 degrees. I would wager it is something else. If it is overheating, check the fans are working and the heatsink is secured.

Comment: The heatpipes in laptops are usually sealed, it may damaged and no longer conduct heat

Comment: @StevenDavison, SLC, Sam, Thank you all. I am away and without tools like paste, air, alcohol, but had screwdrivers and the internet. So, I just opened it up, blew at the exhaust pipes a bit, straightened out the fins, put it back together and now it works.... Checking the temps it cools down a lot better now, and I can boot up fairly demanding games to raise the temps to 50-60c for extended periods without hiccups. Can't pinpoint what fixed it though, or even what exactly the problem was, so not sure if I should post this as a solution?